# WordPress - How to remove parent taxonomy name from the title generated by wp_title()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom taxonomy "Portfolio Categories", and a few these categories say "Cloth", "Shoes", ...

When open some category page, i want the title to be like 'Site Name | Cloth', but with wp_title(), it becomes 'Site Name | Portfolio Categories | Cloth'

How do i remove the "Portfolio Categories" from the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use the wp_title filter (some info here: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_title)

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have a hierarchical custom taxonomy and you want the second-level taxonomies to have URLs which don't include their parent's name in them?

If you are saying that then, as far as I understand it, that's not possible - because it's hierarchical. If you want to have a url such as:

http://yourdomain.com/cloth/

then you'll need a non-hierarchical taxonomy.

The alternative is to set up a custom page template and create a page called 'Cloth' and select your new template for this page. In your template you would create a loop which output only the posts that are in this custom taxonomy.

Comment: Hi there, i'm not talking about permalink, just the html page title appears on your browser's tab. For permalink, you can set the parameter 'rewrite' to false when you register your taxonomy to get the permalink being like, as you mentioned, http://yourdomain.com/cloth/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in your header.php:

```
<title><?php
  global $page, $paged, $post;
  if (is_tax()) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
    $term_title = $term->name;
    echo "$term_title | ";
  } else {
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
  }

  // Add the blog name.
  bloginfo( 'name' );

  // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
  $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
  if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";

  // Add a page number if necessary:
  if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyten' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

  ?></title>
```